# Is there any real potential advantage to having two hearts?

Tags: internal-consistency, xenobiology

One common way sci-fi writers try to make their aliens seem more 'alien' is to give them an extra heart.

This has been done for example in *Babylon 5*, *Dr. Who* and *Alien Nation* among others.

But: **Would a humanoid** (note: in this question humanoid only means two legs, two arms, one head, all in ascending order) **really have any obvious benefits from this biology? Is there a way two hearts could actually be detrimental?**

Comment: My first thought on why two hearts could be an advantage would be for redundancy. But why specifically the heart rather than some other organ? But evolution has found another way to provide redundancy which is by producing more offspring.

Comment: if you have two hearts and you get shot on one, you should still be dying from blood loss, at least with regular hearts

Comment: @kasperd the XCOM game has an interesting insight. Heart is a very vital organ that when punctured generally means you're screwed, we have 2 lobes of brain, a pair of lungs, a pair of kidneys a large stomach but only 1 small heart. They have an implant that creates a secondary heart, allowing one to effectively not have to worry about strikes to the chest area anymore.

Comment: This question should be re-worded as "What are the pros and cons of having two hearts"

Comment: I don't have enough rep on this particular SE to answer a protected question: I'm at a loss after reading over these answers. No one is paying any attention to redundancy, except for one or two who just dismiss it. If the hearts are set up in parallel, so that one can continue working without the other, and if there's a mechanism to divert blood flow away when one fails, then obviously that's beneficial. Of course the creature would have reduced capabilities, and of course it would be taxing on the other heart, but that's better than immediately dying.

Comment: @DCShannon: Nothing is free. Redundancy come at the cost of having to maintain a whole other heart with all the blood flow and nerves required on the off-chance that one of them might fail before you get to reproduce. It's a question of diminishing returns.

Comment: @wjousts It sounds like you're making an argument based on evolutionary bias, but I don't see how that has anything to do with anything. The question didn't ask if two hearts could evolve, it asked whether they would provide any benefit. Reproduction isn't really relevant.

Comment: @DCShannon: Of course reproduction is relevant. That's the whole point of life. Having a second heart has costs. It's not *obviously* beneficial. And the costs maybe much higher than the marginal benefit should one happen to fail.

Comment: It's commonly said among horse people that the horse has five hearts.  There's a mechanism - the frog - in each hoof that pumps blood up the leg every time the horse takes a step.

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned this yet, so I'll make the obligatory Doctor Who reference: Time Lords ("Gallifreyans") in the Doctor Who universe have two hearts, and [it appears to have many benefits](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Binary_vascular_system).

Comment: @Suman there used to be a few comments about it but they've since disappeared...

Comment: @Suman - Umm, the original question mentions it...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: thanks! Sorry I missed it - I did a browser in-page search for "Doctor Who" and didn't find a reference and somehow missed it in the question.

Comment: @gia If something evolved an extra heart, it's easy to believe that sudden drop of blood pressure from that heart might cause it to be locked out of the circulatory system.  Our brains can do something sort of similar with blood supply, we have some redundancy and can kind of only use half of the caraotid stuff if we need to.

Answer (score 61):

It might be better not to think in terms of hearts but chambers. Especially since to a fish, we might be said to have two hearts. Basically, with the evolution of lungs, we evolved one 'heart' for the lungs and one 'heart' for the rest of the body, to keep oxygenated and deoxygenated blood in separate systems (unlike amphibians which have greater mixing of the two types of blood). So if the need to keep the two types of blood (oxygenated and deoxygenated) lead to the evolution of the 4 chambered, dual fish heart system, perhaps there are four types of blood needed to be kept separately leading to the 8 chambered, dual human heart system.

Edit: [Some info/citation](http://evolution.about.com/od/humans/a/Evolution-Of-The-Human-Heart.htm)

Edit2: [image: A helpful picture]

Comment: welcome to the site Plinth

Comment: Well, we do have three(or five hearts) in that case: one heart, two lungs, and two kidneys. Lungs filter air, heart and kidneys filter blood.

Comment: A worthy addition: Octopuses actually *have* three hearts.  One to each set of gills, plus one heart to pump to the rest of the body!

Comment: @CortAmmon Nice! I did not know that!

Comment: Maybe the way to look at it is not separation of systems as compared to fish, but a way to limit pressures. Driving blood through the lungs to oxygenate and then the body to consume would require the output from the lungs to be at high enough pressure to supply the whole body. Driving blood through the body and then the lungs would require vein pressure to be high enough to circulate through the fine capillaries of the lungs. Two separate pressure systems reduces the maximum pressure of the system.

Answer (score 15):

Since heart disease is the leading cause of death in the west, having two hearts has seemingly obvious advantages.

However, heart disease isn't necessarily a result of wear and tear on the heart (though it certainly can be, especially if pumping against great pressure, e.g. high blood pressure or pulmonary hypertension.)

Commonly heart disease that kills people is [coronary heart disease](http://www.cdc.gov/heartdisease/coronary_ad.htm), that is, a buildup of plaque in the arteries supplying oxygen to the heart muscle. In humans, a redundant heart might help if the first one suffers, but in all likelihood, plaque would build up in the arteries of *both* hearts, placing both of them at equal risk of being diseased and giving out more or less at the same relative time.

In humans, therefore, there would be little seeming advantage to a redundant heart. A potential disadvantage is the nutrients and oxygen requirements of the being would be higher for no particular gain.

However, if parts of the body advantageous to survival (e.g. muscles) depend on high flow of oxygenated blood, such an individual may be able to better endure physically demanding tasks. That scenario would also depend on the lungs *not* being the limiting step in blood oxygenation.

In humanoids, if you double the lungs (four lungs) and double the heart, this might give them an advantage. It would also require a much larger chest, though, or devoting another part of the body to additional lungs, which would make the body more fragile and less flexible. The chest is already fairly fragile, requiring a protective cage of ribs, and an injury here is more dangerous than in some other areas of the body. Having more ribs would limit flexibility (your chest isn't very flexible), so that doesn't seen to grant any survival advantage.

Overall, then, I don't think a humanoid form would be better served by two hearts.

Comment: A very well reasoned answer. I like it.

Comment: Instructions unclear, used a toothbrush to clean my heart. Now I have a big mess to clean up...

Comment: Consider also modern medicine. Heart transplants, etc. It may be true that both hearts would probably fail around the same time but it seems pretty likely they wouldn't fail at exactly the same time, giving the victim the opportunity to attempt heart transplant post-what-would-otherwise-have-been-mortem.

Comment: @Devsman - I actually did consider that superficially (it would also be nice to have two donor hearts from one being who died from other causes), but this is asking (to my understanding) what benefit it has to the being; the technology is not stated (we didn't have heart transplants until very, very recently in our time here.) If technology weren't an issue, why not make artificial pumps *en masse*?

Answer (score 11):

In evolutionary terms, the only creatures that needed auxiliary hearts have been giant sauropod dinosaurs, who had to pump blood up considerable distances to the heads. Even then, there wasn't a real second heart, but rather modified structures to ensure blood pressure could be maintained to the head, and also to ensure there would be no damage should the animal lower the head suddenly. Giraffes have analogous structures.

If the creature is exceptionally large, long or tall, then there would be some sort of need for a true second or multiple hearts, but we are talking about creatures the size of Dune Sandworms, or some sort of supersauropod far taller than any discovered to date. It seems that for any creature on Earth using conventional biology, one heart is sufficient.

Comment: So the average daikaijuu has two hearts? Maybe that explains why Gojira became a good guy: he's all heart. This does explain the plot of the second Mechagojira film, though. They misinterpreted the extra organ as a second brain, but it was really a second heart.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus has a main heart, plus an auxiliary heart for each of the 2 gills, total 3.

Answer (score 8):

A [jawed leech](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/210/15/2627.long) has two long, segmented hearts, one running up each side of the body. An [earthworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthworm#Circulatory_system) has five ring-shaped hearts, which sit in the seventh through eleventh of its hundred and fifty sgements. Although neither of these creatures is closely related to any humanoid animal, I can certainly imagine a humanoid on some alien tree of life ending up with a similar circulatory plan.

As [Thucydides](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/38991/7957) mentioned, some people speculate that giant sauropods may have had auxiliary hearts, although there's [no direct evidence](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1634776/) for this. Many animal lineages on Earth, including [theropods](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/aug/01/dinosaurs-shrank-birds-theropods-earth)** and [sauropods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauropoda#Body_size), have undergone striking changes in shape and size. [Vestigial structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestigiality) are common, and the distinction between arms and forelegs is [blurry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipedalism). Thus, on a world where auxiliary hearts actually existed, I could easily imagine a humanoid creature that has an auxiliary heart because it descended from much larger quadrupedal ancestors.

[Level River St](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/38987/is-there-any-real-potential-advantage-to-having-two-hearts#comment109592_38991) mentioned that an octopus has two [branchial hearts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branchial_heart), which move blood through its gills, in addition to its main "systemic" heart. Other [coleoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleoidea), including squid, cuttlefish, and vampire squid, have the same extra hearts, whose [advantages](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02143583) seem to be well understood. Coleoids vary a lot in the numbers and roles of their arms. In some lineages, an arm pair has gone missing, or turned into a pair of sensory filaments not used for grasping. In other lineages, one pair of arms has turned into a pair of tentacles, which are often much longer than the other arms. In the distant future, I suppose some coleoids might end up with one pair of arms, one pair of tentacles, and zero to six pairs of sensory filaments or other non-grasping appendages. If that happens, we could have three-hearted humanoids right here on Earth.

** Under your definition, by the way, I would classify theropods as clearly humanoid!

Answer (score 5):

Aside from redundancy, if a single heart could not be capable of regulating high blood volumes or weights, then this would necessitate the presence of a second heart. The hearts might be contained in dichotomised, greater and lesser, circulation, work in tandem in a single circulatory system, or work in a combination of the two.

Separate hearts can also be considered for the addition of a secondary or equivalent fictitious type of blood, or a liquid analogous to blood that might be inherent to the circulations of certain figures, or as the result of an environment.

Comment: Two types of liquid that need circulation? I like. Perhaps take the current lymphic system and take it a bit further?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'd have liked for alterations such as larger vessels, augmented epitope concentration and diversity, and augmented [memory] leukocyte count to constitute a hyper-being, but that isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 4):

### In theory, yes

(From a certain point of view, we already have two hearts. But let's ignore that sophistry.)

Naively thinking, two (or even three or four) hearts might indeed have a significant advantage in terms of blood pressure.

There would almost certainly be **no** advantages in terms of redundancy.

Coronary heart disease as well as mechanical wear on valves would arguably affect both hearts in the same way, so there is little to gain. A trauma destroying one heart would likely either cause death by exsanguination (puncturing trauma) or would have a good chance of destroying the second heart as well (blunt trauma).
In any case, the backup heart would not be very well-adapted to suddenly having to handle twice the load, either.

However, the pressure advantage remains, if you ignore the practical "implementation problems":

As it stands, the heart generates a short, extreme peak pressure during what we call systole (around 130mmHg on average, but quite possibly twice as much in some conditions) followed by a period of no pressure at all.

Ironically, the heart itself needs blood to survive, too, and blood will only flow through the coronary arteries during the diastole. So, someone, somehow, has to make sure this works. Blood generally has to keep flowing in a kind of steady way.

To add to this, certain organs -- kidneys most notably, but also the brain -- require a certain *minimum* pressure and a certain *average* pressure (of around 70mmHg if I recall correctly) or they will cease to function. This is one of the causes that may e.g. result in the phenomenon known as "shock kidney".

These requirements are a considerable challenge to the arteries which are responsible for keeping that beast running. They must be both muscular and elastic, they must be able to adapt to changing conditions rather quickly and invisibly (you have no idea how much work is necessary when you stand up, just so your brain won't suddenly stop working!), and they are subject to a lot of wear and tear and calcification.
Wouldn't it be nice if we could make the lives of our arteries a bit easier? It turns out we can.

Given two hearts which beat anti-synchronously (or even three hearts running in three-phase mode), in order to achieve the same average pressure, the peak pressure could be *much lower*. The pressure curve would naturally be much smoother, on a more even level. The problem of having to maintain a pressure minimum would magically go away.
This is comparable to an "ordinary" four-stroke car engine in comparison to a six-cylinder or an eight-cylinder, or to a "typical" motorbike engine with one or two cylinders on the other hand side. The "more cylinders" engine will always run a lot smoother, with less noise and vibrations (when assuming the same power, obviously a 10-15x more powerful motor will make more noise!), and with less overall tear and wear.

Now, the problem is getting two hearts to beat in sync, anti-synchronously. If they get out of sync, you will see more or less pronounced interference effects (as known e.g. in electrics or acustics). In the average case, you would have a sub-optimal pressure / blood flow. In the worst case, you would have the pressure waves add up, resulting in a pressure spike twice as high as anticipated. Unluckily, due to the nature of asynchronous waves interfering, that worst case is not just possible, but *guaranteed* to happen regularly.

Thus, you would have to build a system that guarantees that the hearts are, and stay, in sync. Rather than having their own SA node each, there would have to be a single SA node for both hearts, and a "delay circle" of sorts for one heart which delays the signal by exactly one half period length. Of course, the delay circle would have to be communicated from the SA node since it needs to adapt its delay with the heart rate.

That's a *very* complex system with a lot of logic, which is prone to failure. The two hearts would arguably need to be physically separate (rather than just doubling the number of chambers) in order to retain the "wear and tear" advantages. That would however place the SA node (which is a single point of failure) somewhere in between them, presumably in fatty tissue, making it again rather vulnerable to external injury.
If anything happens to this complex system, it all blows up.

The hearts that we currently use have as-dumb-as-can-be designs, which is what makes the design so ingenious. There are no "super clever" bits in them with a lot of synchronization and steering logic. It's membrane potentials spontaneously building up, and firing, and a few conducts and insulators that direct the wavefront in the desired shape. Yes, there are a few regulation mechanisms which can slightly moderate (but not substantially change) the function of certain parts in the conductive system, but all in all it's a hardwired, stubborn little thing that does exactly what it does during your entire life.
There is hardly anything that could go wrong, and this is a good thing. A heart rarely ever fails. You could say it happens on average once in a life.

Comment: Perhaps the hearts could respond to the pressure waves themselves to synchronize. When incoming pressure reaches a certain point they pump.

Answer (score 4):

One alternate reason for a sci-fi species to have an additional heart would go along with another fairly common sci-fi trope; [Heavyworlder](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Heavyworlder).

This is also related to preserving proper blood pressure to the brain.  Like several other answers, a valve system could also do this, but a second heart could help normalize the blood flow against a high local gravity.

Answer (score 2):

For a dual heart system to exist it would need to provide a benefit like you say, some may include:

Survive a natural predator whose deathly attack in the heart to all the proto-hominids. Let's not forget that homo sapiens is for one reason or another one of the only living species of the genus homo. So on another planet the leading humanoid species may have many other species maybe not as intellectually capable within the same genus. Having developed the second heart could be the reason this species became the dominant one on that planet.

Another one as pointed by Plinth, could be to provide alternatives paths for blood. In our body the blood vessels expand to increase the blood influx the parts of the body which most need it (or contract for the opposite effect). A second heart could provide the benefit or a much faster reaction than vasodilation and/or a broader range (total switch on/off vs tuning). If the planet/original environment was susceptible to very abrupt temperature changes which could cause severe hypothermia to biology like ours and where being able to shut off completely within seconds blood supply to skin, internal organs (digestion,...), and keep brain and running muscles oxygenated twice as fast as normal could provide a background for a second heart which would stop pumping at once and let the second heart pump twice as fast a it could if the other heart was also pumping.
Other benefit could be to switch the skin breathing on/off (like bactractians) in presence of toxic gases, or when plunging in water, ...

That second heart being present would then have slowly evolved to become fully redundant with the first one as the humanoids progressed in evolution as a nice additional extra benefit.

You also ask the possible downfall of having a second heart. Like in many systems, the big problem of redundancy is cost:

- energy cost: running a second heart might make the specie need to eat more than others from the same genus
- heightened metabolism cost: running two heart might also make this specie age faster than others from the same genus
- the second heart could be a fairly recent biological addition (evolutionary wise) and many new born may have hearts malformations (lethal or not)

those are of course only a few ideas /suggestions

Answer (score 1):

As Aarthew III pointed out, the body would relying on both hearts until one failed, this would result in the second heart straining to become stronger if the first failed. This would result in (most likely) intense physical training after the first failed. Two solutions come to mind (that haven't been said already);

1. **Valve Hearts** - Instead of having both run at the same time have one run at one time and another if the first fails. This might occur if the heart was closer to the skin and as a result was more likely to be injured. This might be because there are less bones in the body as a result to a lower access to calcium, making bones more 'expensive'
2. **Heavy Blood** - Maybe your creature has very iron rich blood, making having one heart foolish as it would always be under strain. Another alternative is that gravity (or pressure if underwater) is very high having more hearts for the same reason applies. Of course, some may argue that making a stronger heart is more likely. To that I say, since evolution is based on random mutations proving advantageous, two hearts would be chosen over one strong heart.

Answer (score 1):

We could split the work of filtering blood in two hearts if need be, as we do with lungs and kidneys. In that case, it could even happen that we may donate one of the hearts if we could survive on the other(we can donate one kidney if they are in good health, and one is enough to sustain us). But since this is a hypothetical scenario, it would be speculation.

It is said that dinosaurs used to have eight hearts. This could be due to their enormous size and long neck, so additional hearts would be needed to pump blood all the way to the head. Maybe after a few hundred thousand years, if humans needed long bodies or something like that, we may evolve to have extra hearts.

Answer (score 1):

If humans can be argued to have two hearts (because four lobes), then an example of, essentially, *six* hearts in a human-sized mammal is the horse.

Now, this is NOT a humanoid, but the same requirements that require it to have [frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_%28horse%29)s in its feet could drive development of lower-limb hearts in bipedal creatures. In fact, it's even a little surprising that, once we became bipedal, we did NOT develop something like this - instead we had to develop considerably improved blood supply structures to the brain to prevent blacking out when we stand up, and it's still a problem for many of us. One of the many small things that somewhat supports the aquatic ape hypothesis, I feel.

So in short; yes, additional hearts or compressible chambers around the body, either mechanically operated (in sole of foot or back of knee) to automatically cause movement to push blood around the body, seems like it would definitely be an advantage in any large-brained biped which had to switch between long periods of lying prone and periods of rapid dashing.

---

Also, brains. Blacking out is inconvenient. A separate chamber or entire heart devoted purely to feeding blood to the brain seems like it would be useful anywhere that blood pressure to the head will often change significantly, whether by changing attitude (stand/lie), acceleration, or injury.

So you could argue that Klingon-type warrior races would likely have brains protected by a very thick skull and a largely isolated blood supply, the better to survive in combat for longer; as might flying bipeds that pull high g-forces.

Comment: Can you explain to me the difference between the heart of a human and the heart of a horse? I honestly never heard that.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Horses have essentially the same feet, but also have "frogs" at the base of their feet, to help with the pumping of blood (see link in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

One of my fantasy creatures has two hearts. The extra one is only active during fight or flight situations so extra oxygen is sent to the brain.
This creature is also highly regenerative so the backup heart could be used while the other is repaired.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I came up with

*The only way it could possibly be helpful is if you made them alternate. This would make them like kidneys as if you lost one the other could take over. This would however cause some heart strain I'd you lost one as the remaining heart would have to take time to build up the strength to do twice the original work. However there is also more potential for your alien athletes. It also explains how Dr.Who is able to run so well!

*Both working at the same time at the same strength would be very dangerous. Just look up "why giraffes heads don't explode".

Edit: Thanks to Michael I also came up with this. You could have both work at the same time but they would be very weak. If they were too strong then the giraffe head happens. If they were weak there would be no point in having two hearts. As if you lose on e you die. So get them just weak enough to give you minor problems if you lose one but not so strong that your head explodes.

Comment: I actually heard of a man who had exceptional health, it was medically determined he had four kidneys.

Comment: Why would the only way two hearts could be made to work be to have only one working?

Comment: @Michael You could have both work at the same time but they would be very weak. If they were too strong then the giraffe head happens.   If they were weak there would be no point in having two hearts. As if you lose on e you die. That's why my first idea has slightly weak hearts, just weak enough to give you problems if you lose one but not so strong that your head explodes.

Comment: @cst1992 First of all how does that happen? Second kidneys cleanse. You can not die by being too clean. (sorta) You CAN die by having your head explode when you lower it.

Comment: *"You could have both work at the same time but they would be very weak."* That's not what you say in the answer, which very clearly states that *"The only way it could possibly be helpful is if you made them alternate. /.../ if you lost one the other could take over."* Supplementary is not the same thing as alternate.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yes, but I also said "possibly be helpful". Alternating might actually be helpful whereas weak would be basically useless.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Oh XD I just looked back and realized what I said in my 1st comment. My bad. Though I guess that might work too...

Comment: *"Alternating might actually be helpful whereas weak would be basically useless."* Humans (and I believe at least most if not all mammals) have two kidneys. That does not make either kidney "basically useless", even though it is possible to survive having lost one of them.

Comment: @michael Do you want to go to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37593/discussion-between-aarthew-iii-and-michael-kjorling).